# How to collect a flattened Vec from a stream of Results containing a list?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to improve the following method:

```rust
let output: Vec<i32> = stream::iter(vec![1, 2, 3])
    .then(|val| {
        future::ok::<_, ()>(vec![val * 10, val * 10 + 1])
    })
    .try_collect::<Vec<Vec<_>>>()
    .await?
    .into_iter()
    .flatten() // How to flatten directly from the stream?
    .collect();
            
assert_eq!(output, vec![10, 11, 20, 21, 30, 31]);
```

This method works but I think this could be improved because, as you can see, I need to collect two times in order to have the output I want.

This issue comes from the fact that I'm trying to flatten `Result`s that contain a list. I tried to use `try_flatten()` however I absolutely can't make it work. Does anybody have an idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: "Does anybody have an idea on how to achieve this?" Convert the `Result<Vec<T>, E>` to an `impl Stream<Item = Result<T, E>>` or something along those lines? That's basically returning a singleton `Err(e)` if you get an error, and mapping `Ok` over the vector otherwise.

Comment: Yeah this seems the way to go, do you have any idea what method should I use in order to stream values from a future? The `into_stream()` method seems interesting however it seems to stream the array instead of the values. I assume this needs to be combined somehow with `stream::iter` but I'm not very sure how.

Comment: Not really I fear, I've not used streams much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to let you know that I found the [try_concat](https://docs.rs/futures-util/latest/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/futures_util/stream/trait.TryStreamExt.html#method.try_concat) method in the `TryStreamExt` module that does exactly what I wanted.

```rust
let output: Vec<i32> = stream::iter(vec![1, 2, 3])
    .then(|val| {
        future::ok::<_, ()>(vec![val * 10, val * 10 + 1])
    })
    .try_concat()
    .await?;

assert_eq!(output, vec![10, 11, 20, 21, 30, 31]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to use the future iterator adaptors, but you can accomplish the same thing like this:

```rust
use futures::{future, stream, StreamExt};

async fn f() -> Result<Vec<i32>, ()> {
    let mut output = Vec::new();
    let mut stream = stream::iter(vec![1, 2, 3])
        .then(|val| future::ok::<_, ()>(vec![val * 10, val * 10 + 1]));

    while let Some(items) = stream.next().await {
        output.extend(items?);
    }

    assert_eq!(output, vec![10, 11, 20, 21, 30, 31]);
    Ok(output)
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", f().await.unwrap());
}
```

Comment: This answer, even if it works, cannot be accepted sorry. My question was more about intellectual curiosity than make that thing work. IMHO this violates functional programming paradigm by creating a side effet.